# quantmod issue with yahoo finance API 504 Maximum Transaction Time Exceeded

Tags: r

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling quantmod. I've tried using both commands:

```
devtools::install_github("joshuaulrich/quantmod", ref="157_yahoo_502")
devtools::install_github("joshuaulrich/quantmod")
```

I get errors afterwards:

> Error in fetch(key) :    lazy-load database 'C:/Program
>   Files/R/R-3.3.2/library/quantmod/help/quantmod.rdb' is corrupt

When I try to use getSymbols('AAPL'), I get the 504 error:

> Error in download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=",
>   from.m,  :    cannot open URL
>   'https://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=AAPL&a=0&b=01&c=2007&d=4&e=25&f=2017&g=d&q=q&y=0&z=AAPL&x=.csv'
>   In addition: Warning message: In download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=",
>   Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,  :   cannot open URL
>   'https://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=AAPL&a=0&b=01&c=2007&d=4&e=25&f=2017&g=d&q=q&y=0&z=AAPL&x=.csv':
>   HTTP status was '504 Maximum Transaction Time Exceeded'

Please let me know if there is a workaround here to get adjusted close prices, through Yahoo finance or another website.

Comment: `install.packages("quantmod")`? It's on [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/package=quantmod).

Comment: The problem is that your attempt to install quantmod is failing. "https://ichart.yahoo.com" is the old URL that no longer works, not the new URL in the GitHub repo.